# What's the meaning of zsh's default IFS=$' \t\n\C-@' , the "\C-@" part

Tags: zsh

What's the meaning of zsh's default `IFS=$' \t\n\C-@'`, the `\C-@` part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\C-@` denotes null character here. This string inside `$'…'` expands to the actual null character.

Zsh supports null characters in strings. Some other shells don't, so trying to put the null character in their `IFS` doesn't make sense. Compare [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174017/108618).

In addition other shells may not expand `\C-` sequences inside `$'…'` or may not support `$'…'` at all (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371827/108618)).